# Create a SQL table from an ERD, implementing all constraints

Tags: sql, database, implementation, erd

This is the ERD diagram from which I'm to write a SQL query for:

[image]

Comment: please tag DB(Oracle,SQL Server, MySQL etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE product 
  ( 
     ProductId int,
     ProductnName varchar(50) not null, 
     UnitPrice   NUMERIC(10, 2) 
     CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ProductId)
  ) 


CREATE TABLE orders 
  ( 
     orderid int auto_increment, 
     OrderDate Datetime, 
     ProductId int, 
     CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (orderid)
     CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES product(ProductId)

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Oracle. You can create PRODUCT table similarly without `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
  CREATE TABLE Orders (
        OrderID int NOT NULL,
        OrderDate date,
        ProductID int,
        PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
        REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductID)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server

Product Table

```
CREATE TABLE product 
  ( 
     productid   INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     productname VARCHAR(50), 
     unitprice   NUMERIC(17, 2) 
  )
```

Orders Table

```
CREATE TABLE orders 
  ( 
     orderid     INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     OrderDate Datetime, 
     productid   INT, 
     FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES product(productid) 
  )
```